# R rJava will not install on Windows 10

Tags: r

I am trying to install RWeka in RStudio 1.2.5033

I have tried many different ways to install it, I re-installed Java64.  Here is my latest try:

```
install.packages("rJava")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jesse's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rJava 0.9-12 0.9-13              TRUE

installing the source package ‘rJava’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 664898 bytes (649 KB)
downloaded 649 KB

* installing *source* package 'rJava' ...
** package 'rJava' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Generate Windows-specific files (src/jvm-w32) ...
make: Entering directory '/c/Users/JESSE'~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuOekjT/R.INSTALL24344ae86868/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/dlltool --as c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/as  --input-def jvm64.def --kill-at --dllname jvm.dll --output-lib libjvm.dll.a
make: c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/dlltool: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:20: libjvm.dll.a] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/c/Users/JESSE'~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuOekjT/R.INSTALL24344ae86868/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jesse's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Jesse's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Jesse's PC\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps5Y5TC\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: You have to install Java first according to your operative system!

Comment: What do you mean?  My computer says it is a 'x64-based PC.'  I installed jdk-8u261-windows-x64 this morning from Java.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest downloading manually from CRAN an install it. Sometimes there are issues with system confifuration!

Comment: > install.packages("C:/Users/Jesse's PC/Downloads/rJava_0.9-13.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jesse's PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Now I get this error but I do have RTools installed, I reinstalled it and got the same thing.